# Abnormal termination of DataStage. Fault type is 6.

Tags: teradata, datastage

Error:-From previous run 
DataStage Job 719 Phantom 7173
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'CC_Exception'
Abnormal termination of DataStage.
Fault type is 6.  Layer type is BASIC run machine.
Fault occurred in BASIC program DSD.StageRun at address 1550.

Trying to convert a datastage server job from Teradata Enterprice to teradata connector. Getting the above error. Job is stuck in Teradata connector stage and I am able to view the data as well. I have tried same job in different datastage environment and it completed successfully. Couldnt find out much details on this error. Please help out.

Comment: This informatin is not sufficient - Phantom error are always a pain - I would recommend to rebuild the job (or strip it down for test purposes) or to open a PMR

Comment: Thanks for the reply... But I have already tried to rebuild the job but no luck...Same job working fine in different environment.. Something is missing, not sure any environment variable or something.. Couldn't find much details on this error to debug more.